# Point existing projects to new location

Tags: eclipse

I have bunch of projects created in my eclipse, which are java projects. Now what usually happens is, I have new versions of these existing projects comping up.

What I want is, some how go in project config file and just change the root path to new one for a project and it would load all new files.

So basically, its same project just in a new location with new files with same directory structure.

Is there any easy way to handle this?

Comment: Do you mean these are source code projects (like Java projects) or are these binary plugins? If they are source code, aren't you using some sort of version control system?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its called git. You can do exactly what you are looking for via SHA-1s you can jump back to older version, create branches for new features and lots of other fun junk.

Comment: yes, I understand what you are saying, but that is not what I looking for. We are not using git, and don't see moving whole code base to git. So need something else

Comment: The beauty of git is you don't need to moving anything you can happily use it independently of everyone. just `git init` and `git add .` and your ready to start versioning your own environment. Git is completely decentralized.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Eclipse .project file stored with the "new versions", then you could just make a new workspace and import in the new project with File -> Import -> Existing file into workspace. If the new version of the project only has the source files, why not just replace the src folder of the project with the new one?